# Who is the master smithing trainer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Morrowind you could find grandmaster trainers who could train your skills.  My question is who is the most powerful smith in Skyrim?  I'm trying to build a master craftsman but I need the training to get to that goal.

Comment: In my experience, especially for crafting professions, using trainers is **so** expensive that it's not worth it.  Even at 99 it's only going to run you a couple hundred gold in materials to craft enough to skill up.

Comment: I posted this question a while back.  ade my smith.  It was easiest to just make iron daggers and leather gauntlets.  haha..good times

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Eorlund Gray-Mane](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Eorlund_Gray-Mane); the blacksmith who owns the [Skyforge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skyforge) in [Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Whiterun).

Answer (score 5):

The second best smithing trainer is in Riften. To use him, however, you must bring him ten fire salts for his miniquest. After that, he will train you.

Comment: Nobody can train you above 90. You'll need to get those last 10 points the old fashioned way.

Comment: @bwarner That's wrong. The smith in Riften is the *Expert* trainer (up to 75).

Comment: Deleted my incorrect statement, but it is still the case that you don't need to do the fire salts quest to train in Riften.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a fast way to get to 100 smithing, I suggest just buying a bunch of leather strips and iron ingots from all the blacksmiths around the cities and then create a bunch of iron daggers. Doing this it took me around 1 hour and 4000 gold to get to smithing level 100, starting from around level 40.

Comment: Even better, if you procure your own ingots/leather rather than buying them, you can actually *make* a fair bit of money doing this.

Comment: yeah but it's quite a pain to mine, it's faster to just fast travelling everywhere buying iron and leather strips and spamming daggers

Comment: — My own "procurement" tended to involve buckets and turned backs.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Dawnguard DLC installed, Gunmar is a master Smithing trainer. He can be found in Fort Dawnguard if you side with the Dawnguard and advance the quest line far enough that you have gathered some additional recruits.

Edit: A bonus is that like Eorland, he is a merchant so you can purchase training and then sell him stuff to get your gold back.